# How to return a timestamp when a specific value is entered into a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I'm creating a report-styled sheet in Excel, and trying to get a timestamp to automatically be entered in cell "P4" if cell "I6" has a value of "Completed"

I've tried using =IF formulas, which worked, but I'm unable to toggle iterative calculation on the machines this sheet will be working on.

I'm fairly new to writing my own VBA, and I'm having some trouble getting my current code to work. Below is what I currently have, which isn't giving me any results.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As String
    Set r = Cells("I6")
    If r.Value Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If r.Value <> "Completed" Then Exit Sub
    If r.Offset(-2, 7).Value <> "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r.Offset(-2, 7) = Now()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect the code to give me a current timestamp in Cell "P4" once the value "Completed" is entered into cell "I6", but nothing is showing up. How would I correct it in order to get the value based timestamps?

Comment: Does this run without errors? You should instead declare `r` as a range: `Dim r as Range`, then `Set r = Range("I6")`.  That way `r.Value` will trigger.  AFAIK you can't use `.Value` property of a `String`...I don't think such a property exists for that.

Comment: This line is incorrect If r.Value Is Nothing Then Exit Sub .... It would be If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub but there should always be an Range("I6").... You should be getting an error message over that line Set r = Cells("I6")...as Cells("I6") is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this sub is called at every cell's change (and you may use it later for other cell-checks also), check by `Intersect` first, if "your" cell is affected.

The changed range is given as `Target` (which may be a single cell or a complete range, e. g. when you paste on it). If that is intersected with your monitored cell I6, you can go ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RelevantArea As Range

    Set RelevantArea = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I6"))
    If Not RelevantArea Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Completed" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.Range("P4").Value = Now()
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```